# Hood Only Opens When Pulled Up On

Tags: nissan, hood, latch

I've got a 2002 Nissan Almera Perfect 1.8L MTX on which the hood only opens if I pull up on it while someone else yanks the hood release lever.

If I manually set the latch with the hood up, then pull the lever, the latch releases properly every time.  It's only when the hood is in place that the latch has trouble releasing.

Here's what the latch looks like:

[image]

It's in the latched position here.  Just to avoid any confusion, the latch was bolted back in place during all my tests.

**EDIT 16/6/2017**

I tried working some WD-40 style oil into the mechanism, and while it was clearly is operating more smoothly, the hood still won't open unless I pull up on it while someone else pulls the release lever in the cabin.  Is it possible that maybe the spring has just gotten weak and doesn't have enough strength to push the hood up when the lever is pulled?

Anything else I can try, or should I just head to the junk yard for a replacement latch?

Comment: I can think of all kinds of questions related to this, but I do not know what yours is. :-)

Comment: Lubricate a lot. That latch looks rather dry. High friction is a common problem for the hood not popping up.

Comment: Has it had a slight bump at the front in the past? May be just the angle but the panel does not look parallel with the radiator... Could be enough to "trap" the mechanism.

Comment: @SolarMike Yes, it has had a slight bump in the past.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you are looking to overcome the hood failing to release, I see some corrosion where the hood loop is held.

[image]

That can cause it to bind and hold it from releasing. Add some grease here. In fact, the whole latch needs to be lubricated.

Comment: I'll try that and get back to you.

Comment: Good answer, some 3 in 1 oil on the top edge will get worked into the mechanism through gravity and the movement of the parts. It may take a few open-close cycles to work.

Comment: I tried working some WD-40 style oil into the mechanism, and while it was clears operating more smoothly, the hood still won't open unless I pull up on it while someone else pulls the release lever in the cabin.  Is it possible that maybe the spring has just gotten weak and doesn't have enough strength to push the hood up when the lever is pulled?

Comment: It is not likely the spring is going bad, but it is not impossible. Did you lube the hinges too? If the hinges are corroded and binding that spring does not have the strength to overcome that. After that, look for any ways that it may be binding by checking the gaps. If the hood is not sitting square it can cause hinge bind or literally bind against a fender.

Comment: Well, it seems the latch isn't working again.  What I noticed is that if I tighten down the three bolts which hold the latch in place, the hood displays the aforementioned behavior, but if I leave the bolts loose, it opens just fine.  So it must be something with the angle / placement of the latch I suppose...

Answer (score 3):

As I put in my comment and you confirmed by saying it had had a slight bump - I think it is likely that it is slightly out of line as the radiator and metal support do not seem parallel - this could cause the mechanism to bind exactly as you describe.

Comment: Well, it seems the latch isn't working again. What I noticed is that if I tighten down the three bolts which hold the latch in place, the hood displays the aforementioned behavior, but if I leave the bolts loose, it opens just fine. So it must be something with the angle / placement of the latch I suppose...

Answer (score 0):

What I noticed is that if I tighten down the three bolts which hold the latch in place, the hood displays the aforementioned behavior, but if I leave the bolts somewhat loose, it opens just fine. So it must be something with the angle / placement of the latch I suppose...

So my solution is leaving the bolts a bit loosened to change the angle of the latch, and now it's working more or less OK.

Comment: Then your proper solution would be to correct the angle of the latch support panel...